# find files that were modified between 2 and 5 days ago

Tags: bash, find, command

I know of this command `find . -type f -newermt 2010-10-07 ! -newermt 2014-10-08`, which can find the files modified between two dates. But here, the problem is to find files that were 
 modified between 2 and 5 days. So giving dates is not an option. Is there some option of the find command which can do this, or some alternative?

Comment: Did you try playing with -mtime -5 and -mtime +2 ?

Answer (score 3):

From `man find`:

> -mtime n
>
> File's data was last modified less than, more than or exactly n*24 hours ago.  See the comments for  -atime  to  understand  how rounding affects the interpretation of file modification time.
>
> -atime n
>
> File  was  last accessed less than, more than or exactly n*24 hours ago. When find figures out how many 24-hour periods ago the file was last accessed, any fractional part is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file has to have been  accessed  at  least  two days ago.

```
find . -mtime +1 -mtime -5
```

Pay close attention on what value of `n` to chose - it is not that intuitively on first sight.

`+1` means more than `1*24h`, but as the fraction is ignored, it includes `1.9*24h` and the accepted time range starts with exactly `2*24h` (interval `[1,2)`). So the upper border is of interest.

In the case of `-5` it means less than exactly `5*24h`, with the interval for `5` as `[5,6)` or `5<=x<6` in other notation. So there the lower border is of interest.